# How to tag and go to a tag in hg

Tags: mercurial

[This website](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Mercurial+for+Subversion+Users) says `hg tag 1.0` is to get my Mercurial repository to a tag name.

How can I switch my repository to that tag name?

```
$ hg tag myTag1.0
$ <edit more files>
$ hg commit -m "a message"
$ hg how to go back to that tag?
```

And if I make a new `hg commit` here, what will happen? Will it go to the branch of `myTag1.0`? Or will it stay on the default branch?

Answer (score 33):

Tags are not branches. Tags are markers for a particular commit - basically, a way to name commits. That's all. You don't "switch a repository to a tag" any more than you would "switch a repository to a commit" - you can check out a tag, but all that does is roll back your working copy to the corresponding changeset which was tagged.

Branches are created automatically in Mercurial when you commit code that doesn't directly build off of the current head revision.

See here for some more details:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Branch

Answer (score 5):

Just update to the tag name.

```
hg tag 1.0
... make changes ...
hg ci
hg up 1.0
```

Comment: The problem with this is that tags are committed as changes to the .hgtags file. So like this:

Changeset: 350:e6e05f8b7536
tag: tip
description: added tag 1.0 for changset 5d0862b8c30b

Changeset 349:5d0862b8c30b
tag: 1.0
description:
Fixed bugs X and Y, 1.0 pending testing.

But now when you hg up 1.0, the tags don't exist, so any commit here will create a branch (new head) where 1.0 is not tagged.

Not so much a problem, but something you must be aware of.